# How to prevent external magnet rotate a motor

Tags: attack-prevention

A small DC motor working and moving a disc. When device/motor is powered off, a hacker with a strong magnet came and rotated the motor; without touching the motor, just moving the magnet near the motor is sufficient to cause the motor-nucleus to rotate, and hence the shaft rotated and the disc.
A friend told me this happens also with DC stepper motors, but not sure (Currently, no stepper motors available to test.)

Can you suggest a measure/solution to **prevent** magnet to rotate a motor?

Comment: This has nothing to do with security. This is a pure electrical question. The "hacker" in the scenario is incidental.

Comment: You need a latch that stops the movement of motor. Use a mechanical key that controls the position of latch. That way vault won't be open by external magnets.